# Group on Previous Value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data that repeats is name but the dates are different.  I want to group on the step name and date range but not lose some of the pertinent information if it went backwards a stage.

Currently the information looks like:

```
ID  STEP  Start       End  
1   Dis   2014-1-8    2014-1-9
1   Prop  2014-1-9    2014-1-10
1   Prop  2014-1-10    2014-1-11
1   Prop  2014-1-11    2014-1-15
1   Prop  2014-1-15    2014-1-16
1   Bid   2014-1-16    2014-1-17
1   Bid   2014-1-17    2014-1-20
1   Bid   2014-1-20    2014-1-21
1   Prop  2014-1-21    2014-1-23
1   Prop  2014-1-23    2014-1-24
1   Term  2014-1-24    2014-1-25
```

What I am trying to show is

```
ID  STEP  Startgroup       Endgroup  
1   Dis   2014-1-8         2014-1-9
1   Prop  2014-1-9         2014-1-16
1   Bid   2014-1-16        2014-1-21
1   Prop  2014-1-21        2014-1-24
1   Term  2014-1-24        2014-1-25
```

But what I am getting is

```
ID  STEP  Startgroup       Endgroup  
1   Dis   2014-1-8         2014-1-9
1   Prop  2014-1-9         2014-1-24
1   Bid   2014-1-16        2014-1-21
1   Term  2014-1-24        2014-1-25
```

It is making it seem like it didn't go into that step twice

I am using SQL in Big Query to try and solve this.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, step, min(start) Startgroup, max(`end`) Endgroup
from (
  select *, 
    countif(new_group) over(partition by id order by start) group_number
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(start != lag(`end`) over(partition by id, step order by start), true) new_group 
    from data
  )
)
group by id, step, group_number
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  The simplest method for this is two `lag()`s:

```
select id, step, start,
       lead(start) over (partition by id order by start)
from (select t.*,
             lag(step) over (partition by id order by start) as prev_step
      from t
     ) t
where prev_step <> step or prev_step = step;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  id, 
            step, 
            start, 
            end,
            Amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, step ORDER BY start ) As WindowId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start DESC)
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, step ORDER BY start DESC) As ReverseWindowId
    FROM `table`
    )}
```

After working on tis with the idea I got here this also worked